# Simple Docker problem with setting up Discord Bot

Tags: python, bash, docker, discord.py

I am trying to setup following Discord bot: https://github.com/infiniteregrets/QiskitBot

The issue itself is quite easy to reproduce:

1. Clone the GitHub repo (`git clone https://github.com/infiniteregrets/QiskitBot`)
2. Change to the docker folder in particular cloned directory (so, `cd QiskitBot`, then `cd docker`)
3. In `config.py` file, set the value of TOKEN to valid Discord Bot Token.
4. Run `docker build -t qiskitbot .` - This doesn't throw any errors.
5. Run `docker run --privileged -i -t qiskitbot` - This doesn't throw any errors either

After inviting the bot to the server - the bot **is not online**, even though the container is running.

Additional details:

1. Running `docker run --privileged -i -t qiskitbot bash` and then `python3 .` will results in an error: `root@8dba8b248e91:/# python3 . /usr/local/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '//.'`
2. Running `ls` in bash (after running `docker run --privileged -i -t qiskitbot bash`) will print: 
   `bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var`
3. Running `docker-compose up --build` (in **podman** folder) will ask me for input of timezone - can't input anything.

Comment: Do you have to run the commands in the `podman` directory? The `docker` directory does not seem to be complete

Comment: Running "docker run -t qiskitbot ." in podman directory will have same outcome as Additional details 3. (will ask me for input of timezone - can't input anything)